# How to concatenate a function onto a different function?

Tags: linux, gnu, ld, gnu-assembler

Say I have 2 functions: _func and .func. Lets say the code for _func is

```
_func:
    add $10, %rbp
    xor $rax, %rax
```

and the code for .func is:

```
.func:
    sub $10, %rbp
    retq
```

How can I compile/link the two above code blocks to produce a functions that looks like:

```
_func:
    add $10, %rbp
    xor $rax, %rax
    sub $10, %rbp
    retq
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as [c]?

Comment: Have you tried ctrl-c & ctrl-v ? You are calling the assembler and linker at this point. The assembler turns the code into machine code for that platform and the linker combines sections and assigns addresses. So what are you asking for?

Comment: Are you asking how to implement an operation that [*composes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)) two functions, that takes two functions and creates a new function or function-like object that provides the same functionality as the two original ones, in sequence?

Comment: First you write an assembly optimiser that can inline function calls.